# Is there an Ubuntu equivalent to Android's Titanium Backup and TWRP nandroid backup?

Tags: backup, android

Is there an Ubuntu equivalent to Android's Titanium Backup for backing up programs and settings and restoring them upon a new install?

Is there a Nandroid backup that can back up an entire image of your computer where you can restore if anything goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[Aptik](https://launchpad.net/apt-toolkit)

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aptik
```

Tutorial : http://www.howtogeek.com/206454/how-to-backup-and-restore-your-apps-and-ppas-in-ubuntu-using-aptik/